# Check if object inside an object is empty with javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello I have an object:

```
var equippedItems = {
weapon: {},
armor: {},
accessory: {}
};
```

I need a way to check if equippedItems.weapon equals to `''` at some point I am doing something like `equippedItems.weapon = '';` I dont know if it's exactly the same as above object. I already tried using `object.hasOwnProperty` but it seems I cannot use `equippedItems.weapon` in this case, maybe I am doing something wrong? Also note I did read how to check if object is empty already, but it didn't work for my object inside an object.

@Edit:

Like I said, I already read those and they did not give me a straight answer for my question, they did answer how to check if object is empty, but the object was like `object = {};` while mine is like
`object = {
object:{}, 
object2:{}, 
object3:{}};`

Thats why it confuses me.

Comment: `weapon: {}` makes an object with no properties (but an object nonetheless). `equippedItems.weapon = ''` sets that property to an empty string. They are very much not "exactly the same"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just make use of `Object.keys`

```
function isEmpty(obj, propName){
   return Object.keys(obj[propName]).length == 0;
}
```

Another way is to make use of `JSON.stringify` method which will return `{}` if empty

```
function isEmpty(obj, propName){
   return JSON.stringify(obj[propName]) == "{}";
}
```

In both the cases, you would call the function like

```
if(isEmpty(equipmentItems.weapons)){
   equipmentItems.weapons = "";
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer I will try to implement this and see if this works. If I am not mistaken I should use it like:

`function isEmpty(equippedItems, weapon){
   return Object.keys(equippedItems[weapon]).length == 0;
}` I am not sure tho -_- i will keep trying

Comment: sorry for a long wait, I found this question and figured out I should give you "best answer" Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

To check that an object has a property you can use:

```
"weapon" in equippedItems
```

or

```
equippedItems.hasOwnProperty("weapon")
```

Comment: equippedItems has 3 properties which are weapon,armor,accessory. I want to check if weapon/armor/accessory is empty I believe that I already tried your method. I will try it again tho